# How to build an array of vectors, which can rotate, using C++

Tags: c++, vector, physics

So I have written the a code for the lattice that does:

```
const int Lx = 5, Ly = 5;
const int L = Lx*Ly;

inline void vector_lattice(){

    for (int i = 0; i < L+1; i++){
        s[i]=0.0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
        s[i] =1;
   }
}
```

This was fine for what I was doing, but now I want to have an actual lattice of vectors begin gin at x1,y1 and stoping at x2,y2. But I want to ultimately rotate those vectors 'sin(theta)' or something like that, so I need  to have positions like x1,y1,x2 and y2 to plot arrows that represent the directions of all the vector in the lattice, in this case 25 arrows in a lattice 5x5.

Any one knows what I'd need to change to achieve that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more specific what you're asking? I'm not sure what "I need a the all positions" means.

Comment: Done, hope it's clearer now!

Comment: It's still not entirely clear, but if I understand correctly then you could store the lattice sites in a `std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, std::pair<int,int>>` where the first pair stores the `(x,y)` co-ordinates and the second pair stores the direction of the "spin" at these points. Then any rotations can be applied to this second pair for what you want to achieve.

Comment: How do I define the size though or the direction? Might sound very stupid.

Comment: we're both using std::pair<double,double> to represent the vector.  If you chose to store it as radians and magnitude, just make sure that's obvious in the code, maybe with struct {double radians, magnitude;} lattice_vector;

Comment: ArchbishopOfBanterbury covered how to iterate over all when you perform operations like rotate (although not how to cover a specific range). My answer covers how to iterate over a fixed integer x,y range, but not how to perform the operations.  Between the two, you can probably get everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you know the physics, but not the programming. I would make a 2-dimensional array, so you can access it like s[x][y] = whatever; However you are asking how to iterate over a 2d array represented in a 1d array, and I can help you there.

All you need is a 1 to 1 mapping of x,y coordinates to the array's index. It doesn't really matter what that mapping is, as long as it is 1to1, but here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
typedef std::pair<double, double> physics_vector;

const int Lx = 5, Ly = 5;
const int L = Lx*Ly;
int get_index(int x, int y) { return y * Ly + x; }

// almost forgot
int get_x(int index) { return index % Lx; }
int get_y(int index) { return index / Lx; }

class lattice : public std::vector< physics_vector >{
public:
    lattice() { resize(L); }
};

void iterate_over_lattice(std::vector<physics_vector> &s){

    for (int y = 0; y < Ly; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++){
            int index = get_index(x, y);
            s[index] = physics_vector(1, 0);
            std::cout << index << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    lattice s;
    iterate_over_lattice(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: iterate_over_lattice could take a function pointer, and call that function for every point.  That would let you pull the std::cout side effects out of the iteration, where it looks ugly.

Comment: Maybe in hindsight, I should have figured out how to do this with std::array, just to avoid the word vector, which means one thing in c++ and something completely different in this application.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper around a `std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, std::pair<double,double>>>` which represents a lattice site - its co-ordinates and direction respectively in each `std::pair`. Something similar to below could work well,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class lattice_sites {
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<
        std::pair<int,int>, 
        std::pair<double,double>
        >> lattice_vector;
public:
    lattice_sites() : _lat_vec() {}
    // create a lattice site with given position and direction
    void create_site(const std::pair<int,int>& _coords, 
        const std::pair<double,double>& _drctn) {
        _lat_vec.push_back(std::make_pair(_coords, _drctn));
    }
    // rotate all lattice sites
    void rotate_all(const double& _rot_angle) {
        for (auto& x : _lat_vec) {
            x.second.first = std::cos(_rot_angle); // rotate x-direction
            x.second.second = std::sin(_rot_angle); // rotate y-direction
        }
    }
    // write to stream
    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& _os) {
        for (const auto& x : _lat_vec) {
            _os << x.first.first << " " << x.first.second << "\t" // coords
                << x.second.first << " " << x.second.second << "\n"; // direction
        }
        return _os;
    }
private:
    lattice_vector _lat_vec;
};
```

Then you can manipulate instances of this class as follows,

```
int main(void) {
    lattice_sites sites;
    const int n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sites.create_site(std::make_pair(i,i), std::make_pair(0.0,0.0));
    }
    double rotation_angle = 0.5; // radians
    sites.rotate_all(rotation_angle);
    sites.write(std::cout);
}
```

This may require some tweaking (and optimisations such as using `resize` in the constructor if you already know the size of the lattice), but you should get the gist of it.